# Equivalent of `remember (f x) as y eqn:H; clear H; clear x`?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, ltac

Sometimes I have a proof that is best done by projecting into a different space. At the moment I do the following:

```
remember (f x) as y eqn:H; clear H; clear x.
```

I tried to automate this with Ltac:

```
Ltac project x y :=
  let z := fresh in
    remember x as y eqn:z; clear z; clear x.
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: Ltac variable x is bound to f x which cannot be coerced to a variable.
```

What's the issue here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are trying to call your tactic like this:

```
project (f x) y.
```

If you unfold the definition you gave, you will see that this call ends with

```
clear (f x).
```

This call is the culprit: you can only clear variables, not arbitrary expressions.  Here is a possible fix.

```
Ltac project x y :=
  match x with
  | ?f ?x' => 
    let z := fresh in
    remember x as y eqn:z; clear z; clear x'
  end.
```

Since you are generating an equation that you never use, it is better to replace `remember` with `generalize`:

```
Ltac project x y :=
  match x with
  | ?f ?x' => generalize x; clear x'; intros y
  end.
```

You might also consider using the [ssreflect](http://math-comp.github.io/math-comp/) proof language, which considerably simplifies this kind of context manipulation.  Instead of calling `project (f x) y`, we could just use

```
 move: (f x)=> {x} y.
```

This is much more flexible.  For instance, if you wanted to do something similar with an expression with two free variables, you would only have to write

```
move: (f x1 x2)=> {x1 x2} y.
```